# Is there a constant $c$ such that $\sigma_1(A)\leq c\rho(A)$ for all $n\times n$ matrices $A$?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, singular-values

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix. Denote by $\sigma_1(A)$ the largest singular value of $A$, and $\rho(A):=\max_\mu\{{|\lambda_\mu|}\}$ the radius of the eigenvalues $\lambda_\mu$ of $A$.

As is well-known, there is
\begin{eqnarray}
\rho(A)\leq\sigma_1(A).
\end{eqnarray}

My question is the converse:

Is there a constant $c$ such that
\begin{eqnarray}
\sigma_1(A)\leq c\rho(A),
\end{eqnarray}
for all $n\times n$ matrices $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider for instance $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ The answer is yes, with $c=1$, when $A$ is selfadjoint.